# ng-select change color on disabled state for items in the option list angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am trying to style the disabled state for a list of options, using `ng-select` in Angular.

What is the css class of ng-select for disabled state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng-select-disabled
```

Example of usage:

```
.ng-select-disabled > .ng-select-container {
  color: red;
}
```

Haven't tried, but it may also work just:

```
.ng-select-disabled {
  color: red;
}
```